# How to get all details for not answerer calls between 2 dates in genesys cloud?

Tags: genesys, genesys-platform-sdk

I'm working on **genesys cloud** application.

I need to get client, agent and call information for all **not answered outbound calls** for a day or between 2 dates by an API.

Is there an API do that?

Answer (score 0):

This end point will work for you it will provide data of date intervals by passing dates in interval.
https://api.mypurecloud.com/api/v2/analytics/conversations/details/query

Pass interval  in the request in below format.
1."interval":"2021-11-09T18:29:00.000Z/2021-11-09T18:30:00.000Z" in request.

Pass originatingdirect as outbound in request as shown below.
2."originatingdirection":"outbound.

Then this will provide you info of calls whose convesration time lie in the interval and are outbound calls.

You can find documentation of request and response in the below url
https://developer.genesys.cloud/api/rest/v2/conversations/

In response json:-
Agent info is in userid field where purpose is agent in participant object of response.
You can get the name of agent using
https://developer.genesys.cloud/api/rest/v2/users/#get-api-v2-users

Comment: Requires some editing.